# Preventing null (or empty string values in the db)

Tags: database, go, go-gorm, notnull

I'm using PostgreSQL and GORM in my Go app.

I thought that using the sql tab of `sql:"not null"` would do the trick of preventing a null entry, but when go initializes structs with a string type then it defaults to an empty string which is not the same as null in the db.

I am wondering if there is a way to prevent this from happening in a struct definition so I wouldn't have to strictly enforce it at all levels in the application code.

Comment: An empty string is the "not null" version of a string, no?

Comment: its not enforcing it for me..If I got to my db manually and try to enter a null field then it says it violates not null constraint, but if I enter '' then it accepts it

Comment: @deltaskelta: That's exactly what it should do. What's your question?

Comment: the last line of my question is what I am asking. Is there a way to prevent an empty string from being valid without strictly enforcing it through application code?

Comment: No, there's no way within a struct definition to specify that some specific value is invalid.

Comment: why don't you declare your field as sql.NullString?

Comment: Use defaults instead `gorm:"default:'empty'"`. Or prevent calls to db.Create at application level.

Answer (score 28):

You can solve this problem of preventing '' (empty) string insertion into the database by `using default: null` and `not null` constraint together. SO if Struct field values are empty it will be consider as default value `null` and gorm will throw an error.

> `gorm:"unique;not null;type:varchar(100);default:null"`

Example is:

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Email  string    `gorm:"unique;not null;type:varchar(100);default:null"`

}
```

SO gorm for empty `User.Email`  will throw an error.

Comment: This works nicely. Nice way to solve this! Setting it this way, trying to pass in empty Email would create an error similar to: `ERROR: null value in column "email" of relation "users" violates not-null constraint (SQLSTATE 23502)`

Comment: This works for sqllite but mysql throws an error that Error 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for

Answer (score 0):

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Email  string    `gorm:"unique;not null;type:varchar(100);default:null"`

}
```

When I use like this it works but when I automigrate I did had error from migration gorm

Comment: Answer is a comment on another answer

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32752795)

Answer (score 0):

Add a isValid() function to your model that returns false if a not null field is in its defalt (0 for int, "" for string, etc), and before insert, check if valid, return an error if not valid, else, nil.